# Order of linkinkg libc and libpthread on FreeBSD

Tags: gcc, linker, pthreads, freebsd, libc

I have this simple [c-code](http://pastebin.com/tDf2mMnK)

It works fine when i link it as

```
gcc  -g app.c.o  -o app  -lrt -lpthread -lc
```

But if we change order of linking libc and libthread

```
gcc  -g app.c.o  -o app  -lrt -lc -lpthread
```

it does not work.

We know on FreeBSD stubs of pthread-functions in libc are made as weak reference.
For example

```
objdump -T /lib/libc.so.7 | grep pthread_cond_signal
00000000000e2bf0  w   DF .text  0000000000000011  FBSD_1.0    pthread_cond_signal
```

It means order of linking is not matter. Why so?

Comment: I've found the same issue http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-hackers/2011-April/035083.html, but i dont undestand why linker choose libc's fork, not libthr. fork is made as weak reference too.

Answer (score 1):

Compile and link using the option `-pthread`. Note the missing "ell".

---

**Update**:

- `-pthread` instructs all tools involved in creating a binary (pre-processor, compiler, linker) to take care that the application/library to be build runs as intended. (This obviously is only necessary if the source makes use of any member(s) of the `pthread_*`-family of functions.)
- Whereas `-lpthread` links a library called `libpthread`, nothing more and nothing less.

The difference in detail is implementation specific.

Note: if `-pthread` has been specified `-lpthread` is not necessary as well as not recommended to be specfied.

Comment: But I want to understand this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the behavior is that the linker only does a single pass through the libraries in the provided order to resolve symbols.

So, it needs to know about the `pthread_*` functions from `-lpthread` before it can resolve references to those functions in later libraries.

I believe the use of weak references is so that you can have functions in `-lc` that need `-lpthread`, but if you don't reference those functions in `-lc` than it isn't an error that its references to `pthread_*` couldn't be resolved.